# get HTML from QWebEnginePage in QWebEngineView using Lamda

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, lambda, qwebpage

I want to get the HTML code of a web page opened in QWebEngineView I use toHtml() function in QWebEnginePage Class like this

```
QWebEnginePage *page = ui->widget->page();
QString HTML = "";
page->toHtml([&HTML](QString html){qDebug() << "code \n\n\n" << html;});
```

the HTML code of html page appeared in qDebug good without problem
the problem here is when I want to use HTML string outside the function when I show the size of the HTML varible it is equal to zero and empty
so I tried this

```
QWebEnginePage *page = ui->widget->page();
QString HTML = "";
page->toHtml([&HTML](QString html){HTML = html;}); // crash
qDebug() << "i want to use HTML here outside the function = " << HTML;
```

but the app crash show so what should I do so I put the HTML data in the HTML variable so I can use it outside the function 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the fact that the lambda is run asynchronously. So it is really called after you have exited the method in which you call `toHtml` method and that also explains the crash - `HTML` is a local variable within the method which has already exited so the lambda just randomly corrupts the memory used to be occupied by `HTML` variable.

What you want to do here is to synchronize things i.e. block your method until the lambda is executed. It can be done with `QEventLoop` but that would need to involve sending a special signal from the lambda to indicate the fact that the lambda finished executing. So it would look somewhat like this (non-tested):

```
class MyClass: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyClass(QWebEnginePage & page, QObject * parent = 0);

    void notifyHtmlReceived();

    QString getHtml();
    void setHtml(const QString & html) { m_html = html; }

Q_SIGNALS:
    void htmlReceived();

private Q_SLOTS:
    void requestHtmlFromPage();

private:
    QWebEnginePage & m_page;
    QString m_html;
};

MyClass::MyClass(QWebEnginePage & page, QObject * parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    m_page(page)
{}

void MyClass::notifyHtmlReceived()
{
    emit htmlReceived();
}

QString MyClass::getHtml()
{
    QEventLoop loop;
    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(htmlReceived()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));

    // Schedule the slot to run in 0 seconds but not right now
    QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(requestHtmlFromPage()));

    // The event loop would block until the lambda receiving the HTML is executed
    loop.exec();

    // If we got here, the html has been received and the result was saved in m_html
    return m_html;   
}

void MyClass::requestHtmlFromPage()
{
    m_page.toHtml([this](QString html)
                  {
                      this->setHtml(html);
                      this->notifyHtmlReceived();
                  });
}
```

Comment: this is forbidden.