# how to get html source code from QWebEnginePage in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwebenginepage

I am trying to get html code from the url with QWebEnginePage and QWebEngineView.

i found this answer but realy dont undrsestad the syntax.

[get HTML from QWebEnginePage in QWebEngineView using Lamda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45363190/get-html-from-qwebenginepage-in-qwebengineview-using-lamda)

**so my question is how can i get html source code from URL with  QWebEnginePage in pyqt5?**

thanks in advance and sorry about my english skill

Comment: @eyllanesc tnx so much. i did not fund this by sercheing... idont know why.. am i gonna ban for asking duplicate question?

Comment: No, you will not be banned, but the question will be probably deleted sooner or later. Also, please avoid unnecessary formatting, thanks, greetings and apologies for your English (if we are not able to understand you, we will ask you for clarifications, otherwise it's useless to point it out, we will understand that on our own).